# How to customize command ribbon for marketing list members in Dynamics CRM 2015 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working with Dynamics CRM 2015 Online, and I'm looking for a way to modify the command ribbon that displays when viewing a list of Marketing List members from a Marketing List record.

For example: if I open an existing Marketing List record, and then use the sitemap tiles to go to Marketing List Members, I'm looking at a sub-grid view of marketing list members. I want to add a button to that command ribbon.

Looking at the entities it appears that what I am looking for is the `ListMember` entity, but that entity isn't in the list of entities and so I can't seem to customize it at all.

Has anyone successfully edited this before or am I stuck here?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309420.aspx : Subgrid ribbons
The entity subgrid ribbon is a contextual group with a collection of tabs that have an Id attribute value beginning with Mscrm.SubGrid.<entity logical name>. For example, the tab with the text "Accounts" on account entity sub grid is Mscrm.SubGrid.account.MainTab.

Comment: I have reviewed that, I am aware of how the various command ribbons work for an entity.  The problem is that the `ListMember` entity is not available in the default solution xml or even listed in the UI when I look at all the entities within the default solution.  I'm wondering about `ListMember` specifically if anyone has found a way to customize its subgrid command ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not possible to modify because there is no way to retrieve the "listmember" entity ribbon from your solution.**

Since it does not allow you to get the entity tools like the Ribbon Workbench have no way of allowing you customize it.

[listmember entity - ribbon workbench](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/141009)

Comment: That's what I was worried about, but wanted to confirm if that was true or if anyone had found another way to edit it.  Thanks.

Comment: @AK3800 it might be possible to add a button to a command bar using JavaScript in an unsupported way. I am not sure, but you may give it a hit & try if it is really worth for you.